# MenuItem Visibility binding to RelayCommand CanExecute with Parameter

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, relaycommand

I'm using Josh Smith RelayCommand class in a WPF MVVM app for creating my commands inside my ViewModel:

For example:

```
ICommand RemoveAllCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(OnRemoveAll, CanRemoveAll);
```

I am calling this command from a ContextMenu:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <MenuItem Header="Remove All" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.RemoveAllCommand,
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.Header}" />
```

Everything works fine, except that my MenuItem's is still visible but disabled, I would like to set the Visibility to Collapsed so that my MenuItem doesn't show up when `CanExecute` in Relay Command returns false.

I tried to set a binding to Visibility property, but I don't know how to bind to my `CanRemoveAll(object obj)` method with parameter. I also thought about using a DataTrigger but I'm not sure how to do it.

Here is my `CanRemoveAll` method in the ViewModel:

```
    public bool CanRemoveAll(object param)
    {
        GoldTreeNodeViewModel gtn = param as GoldTreeNodeViewModel;
        return (gtn != null && gtn.Children != null && gtn.Children.Count > 0);
    }
```

From the RelayCommand class:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            if (_canExecute != null)
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            if (_canExecute != null)
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public Boolean CanExecute(Object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute((T) parameter);
    }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated,

Comment: Can you please show the code of CanRemoveAll in VM and also from where you Raising CanExecuteChanged.

Comment: Just added that info to the question.. Also I'm not Raising the `CanExecuteChanged` explicitly anywhere, I think the `RelayCommand` and WPF internals take care of that as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <MenuItem Header="Remove All" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.RemoveAllCommand,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.Header}" 
                  Visibility="{Binding DataContext.RemoveVisibility,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}"
                  />

private Visibility _removeVisibility;

    public Visibility RemoveVisibility
    {
        get { return _removeVisibility; }
        set { _removeVisibility = value; Notify("RemoveVisibility"); }
    }

    public bool CanRemoveAll(object param)
    {
        GoldTreeNodeViewModel gtn = param as GoldTreeNodeViewModel;
        bool result= (gtn != null && gtn.Children != null && gtn.Children.Count > 0);
        if (result)
            RemoveVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        else
            RemoveVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        return result;
    }
```

I think that DataContext you have binded correspond to your ViewModel . I hope this will help.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense, although I may need to use my bool to Visibility converter but that's minor. Let me try it, and thanks for the suggestion

Comment: yes you can do that and create Converter to Convert bool to Visibility.

Comment: Although I'm not really sure about creating a Visibility type property in the VM, that sounds more like View related, but I could create a `public bool IsRemoveAllVisible` property...

Comment: That worked, but I wonder if there is an alternate way of doing it without having to create additional Visibility properties in the VM for each MenuItem...

Comment: I made that Visibility Property just to give you an idea how you can do that otherwise I would have to do more work like creating Converter and etc. And about Handling all MenuItems with single property hmmm for that you can create string property (assign Command params to it) and bind this property to all MenuItems Visisbility Property and Create Converter and in this pass Header value like "Add" as Converter parameter and then in that converter Compare if value and Converter param is same then set Visibility Visble or Collapsed.  This is also just an idea am not sure.